Operators algebra for quantum mechanics
I am taking my first quantum mechanics course and I am a bit lost in operators algebra. These are the main questions I have:

Why can we write this kind of equations? $$ Ô \psi = o\psi $$
What I mean is that $Ô$ may have more than one eigenvalue so I feel like this equation should be $$\sum_i o_i \cdot \psi $$
What does the eigenstate of an operator mean and how should I use it in a computation ?
For example when I have $$\langle p|\hat{p}|p'\rangle$$how should I do this computation ? From my understanding, this is

$$\int{ \langle p|p\rangle \langle p|p'\rangle}dp'$$ but our teacher did not explain why this is so, so I am always guessing from previous computations instead of knowing what I am doing.

Finally this may be the same question as the previous one but I am not able to see the link, when computing the hamiltonian operator of a state, what does it mean to convert $\langle x |\hat{p}^2|\psi\rangle$ into $$\int{\langle x|\hat{p}|x'\rangle \langle x'|\hat{p}|\psi\rangle dx}'$$

I guess these are very basic questions but I need to understand them in order to keep learning, so thank you for every answer.


The equation $$\hat{O} \psi = o ~ \psi \tag{1} \label{1}$$ is an eigenvalue equation you should already be familiar with from your course on linear algebra (replace $\hat{O}$ by an $n \times n$ matrix and interpret $\psi$ as an $n$-dimensional vector). In quantum mechanics, you are looking for solutions of eq. \eqref{1} (where $\hat{O}$ is a hermitean operator) for vectors $\psi \ne 0$ in your Hilbert space (usually a space of functions). In general, you will find many possible eigenvalues $o_1, o_2, \ldots \in \, \mathbb{R}$ with associated eigenvectors (eigenfunctions) $\psi_1, \psi_2,\ldots$, such that $\hat{O} \psi_1= o_1 \psi_1, \, \hat{O} \psi_2=o_2 \psi_2, \ldots$. Your second equation does not make sense. In fact, in the case of a general element $\phi$ of your Hilbert space (not necessarily being an eigenvector of the operator $\hat{O}$), you can write $\phi$ as a linear combination of the eigenvectors $\psi_i$, i.e.  $\phi=\sum\limits_i c_i \psi_i$ and because of linearity you obtain $$\hat{O} \phi= \hat{O} \sum\limits_i c_i \psi_i =\sum\limits_i c_i o_i \psi_i.$$

$\langle p \lvert \hat{p} \rvert p^\prime\rangle  =\langle p \lvert p^\prime \rvert p^\prime\rangle = p^\prime \langle p \lvert p^\prime \rangle = p^\prime \delta(p-p^\prime)=p\delta(p-p^\prime) $

The identity operator $\mathbb{I}$ can be written in the form $$\mathbb{I}=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \, dx^\prime \lvert  x^\prime \rangle \langle x^\prime \rvert. $$ This is the continuous version of the relation $$\mathbb{I} = \sum\limits_i \lvert \psi_i \rangle \langle \psi_i \rvert,$$ where $\psi_1, \psi_2, \ldots$ is an orthonormal basis (complete orthonormal system) of your Hilbert space.

Consulting a good text-book on QM and refreshing basic concepts in finite-dimesional vector spaces (basis of a vector space, eigenvalue, eigenvector, spectrum of a linear operator, scalar product, vector space with complex scalar product, orthonormal basis, normal operators, hermitean operators, unitary operators, spectral theorem for normal operators, etc.) might be helpful.



So many things are making sense for me now, thank you very much !
